# Interpretation of final solutions in showing divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n}n!}{n^{n}}$ and its reciprocal. - Spivak Ch 23 - # 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I have a question in regards to the final step in interpreting the solutions to a set of related questions in *Spivak's Calculus - Ch.23 -#2*. The following is the question:

[image]

Of importance is the relationship which we worked out in Problem 22-13:

> $$\frac{n^{n}}{e^{n-1}} < n! < \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n}}$$

**a)** After some manipulation of the above inequality and some algebra I arrive at the following:

$$e < \frac{e^{n}n!}{n^{n}}$$

And it is here that I got stuck. The solution stated that the series diverges. Since we can't use the ratio test, the idea of comparing $a$ to $e$ will not work. So how did the author conclude that the series diverges? What test was used?

**b)** I've just figured it out, but for completeness I'll comment on it here.  So once again using the given inequality, and some algebra you get the relationship:

$$\frac{n^{n}}{e^{n}n!} = \frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n}n!} > \frac{1}{(n+1)}\bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg)^{n} = \frac{1}{(n+1)\bigg(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}\bigg)^{n}} > \frac{1}{2e(n+1)}$$

Now this can used as the terms of a harmonic series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$, which diverges by comparison.

But back to **a)**, what test was used to draw the conclusion? At first I thought it was using $\frac{e^{n}n!}{n^{n}}$ as my "$a$" term to compare, but I son't think that is the case.

Comment: You can again use the comparison test. Or you can note that the terms (being bounded below by $e$) don't converge to $0$.

Comment: Yes, what Spivak intended (if I may be presumptuous) is that you observe that the terms certainly do not go to $0$ because of that (very positive) lower bound.